# Restcomm gmlc configuration issue no local SSN is present for primary Address

Tags: restcomm

I'm facing an issue while trying to configure restcomm gmlc on windows server 2008 R2. I Get the this message

[image]

The picture bellow are the settings for HLR and the Windows server

[image]

And bellow are the settings

**GmlcManagement_gmlcproperties.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gmlcgt value="237694000089"/>
<gmlcssn value="145"/>
<hlrssn value="6"/>
<mscssn value="6"/>
<maxmapv value="3"/>
```

**Mtp3UserPart_m3ua1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<heartbeattime value="10000"/>
<aspFactoryList>
    <aspFactory name="timbr_asp1" assocName="timbr_ass1" started="false" maxseqnumber="256" aspid="2" heartbeat="false"/>
</aspFactoryList>
<asList>
    <as name="timbr_as1" minAspActiveForLb="1" functionality="IPSP" exchangeType="SE" ipspType="CLIENT">
        <routingContext size="1">
            <rc value="102"/>
        </routingContext>
        <networkAppearance value="8"/>
        <trafficMode mode="2"/>
        <defTrafficMode mode="2"/>
        <asps>
            <asp name="timbr_asp1"/>
        </asps>
    </as>
</asList>
<route>
    <key value="89:42:3"/>
    <routeAs trafficModeType="2" as="timbr_as1"/>
</route>
```

**SccpStack_sccpresource2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<remoteSsns>
    <id value="1"/>
    <value remoteSpc="42" remoteSsn="6" remoteSsnFlag="0" markProhibitedWhenSpcResuming="false"/>
</remoteSsns>
<remoteSpcs>
    <id value="1"/>
    <value remoteSpc="42" remoteSpcFlag="0" mask="0"/>
</remoteSpcs>
<concernedSpcs/>
```

**SccpStack_sccprouter2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rule>
    <id value="1"/>
    <value ruleType="Solitary" loadSharingAlgo="Undefined" originatingType="RemoteOriginated" mask="K" paddress="1" saddress="-1" networkId="0">
        <patternSccpAddress pc="42" ssn="6">
            <ai value="18"/>
            <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="2" np="1" nai="4" digits="237694000089"/>
        </patternSccpAddress>
    </value>
    <id value="2"/>
    <value ruleType="Solitary" loadSharingAlgo="Undefined" originatingType="LocalOriginated" mask="K" paddress="2" saddress="-1" networkId="0">
        <patternSccpAddress pc="89" ssn="145">
            <ai value="16"/>
            <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="1" np="1" nai="4" digits="*"/>
        </patternSccpAddress>
    </value>
</rule>
<routingAddress>
    <id value="1"/>
    <sccpAddress pc="89" ssn="145">
        <ai value="19"/>
        <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="2" np="1" nai="4" digits="237694000089"/>
    </sccpAddress>
    <id value="2"/>
    <sccpAddress pc="42" ssn="6">
        <ai value="17"/>
        <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="1" np="1" nai="4" digits="*"/>
    </sccpAddress>
</routingAddress>
<longMessageRule/>
<sap>
    <id value="1"/>
    <value mtp3Id="1" opc="42" ni="2" networkId="1">
        <mtp3DestinationMap>
            <id value="1"/>
            <value firstDpc="1" lastDpc="16384" firstSls="0" lastSls="255" slsMask="255"/>
        </mtp3DestinationMap>
    </value>
</sap>
```

**SCTPManagement_sctp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<connectdelay value="5000"/>
<servers/>
<associations>
    <name value="timbr_ass1"/>
    <association name="timbr_ass1" assoctype="CLIENT" hostAddress="172.22.118.131" hostPort="2609" peerAddress="192.168.212.185" peerPort="2609" serverName="" ipChannelType="0" extraHostAddresseSize="0"/>
</associations>
```

**TcapStack_management.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dialogidletimeout value="60000"/>
<invoketimeout value="30000"/>
<maxdialogs value="5000"/>
<dialogidrangestart value="1"/>
<dialogidrangeend value="2147483647"/>
<donotsendprotocolversion value="false"/>
<statisticsenabled value="false"/>
```

Comment: Hi there Patrick, 

I would suggest you raise an issue over on the GitHub project (https://github.com/RestComm/gmlc), to get an answer on something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I see quite a few issues in the raised question, albeit I think your problem is in jboss-beans.xml file (will get there later), it's important to clarify them as they could potentially be cause of problems.

1) SSN should be **145** as for specifications, and you got it right in Restcomm GMLC's configuration files, but in the image it appears as 147 (which is not appropriate, as that is the SSN for gsmSCF, not for GMLC). Are you sure the MNO has 145 and it's only a typo in the image?

2) MSC SSN is 8, not 6 as you put it in *mscssn* value at *GmlcManagement_gmlcproperties.xml*. Modify that to **8** please.

3) Are you sure about the *routingContext* and *networkAppearance* values or did you just copied them from the simulator profile?

Having that in mind, your main problem most likely reside at the following two configuration files:

1) Check $GMLC_HOME/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/restcomm-gmlc-server/META-INF/**jboss-beans.xml** *TCAP Service* section... it should look like this:

```
    <!-- ==================================================================== -->
    <!-- TCAP Service -->
    <!-- ==================================================================== -->
    <bean name="GMLC_TcapStack" class="org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.tcap.TCAPStackImpl">
        <constructor>
            <parameter>TcapStack</parameter>
            <parameter>
                <inject bean="GMLC_SccpStack" property="sccpProvider" />
            </parameter>
            <parameter>145</parameter>
        </constructor>
        <property name="persistDir">${jboss.server.data.dir}</property>
        <!--
        <property name="dialogIdleTimeout">60000</property>
        <property name="invokeTimeout">30000</property>
        <property name="maxDialogs">25000</property >
        -->
    </bean>
```

First, are you sure **145** is there? Then and again, as pointed out in 1), are you sure the MNO and your configuration are concordant?

2) Your routing rule configuration at **SccpStack_sccprouter2.xml** might lead you to problems, set *pc* and *ssn* values to **0** in *patternSccpAddress*, like this:

```
<rule>
    <id value="1"/>
    <value ruleType="Solitary" loadSharingAlgo="Undefined" originatingType="RemoteOriginated" mask="K" paddress="1" saddress="-1" networkId="0">
        <patternSccpAddress pc="0" ssn="0">
            <ai value="18"/>
            <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="2" np="1" nai="4" digits="237694000089"/>
        </patternSccpAddress>
    </value>
    <id value="2"/>
    <value ruleType="Solitary" loadSharingAlgo="Undefined" originatingType="LocalOriginated" mask="K" paddress="2" saddress="-1" networkId="0">
        <patternSccpAddress pc="0" ssn="0">
            <ai value="16"/>
            <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="1" np="1" nai="4" digits="*"/>
        </patternSccpAddress>
    </value>
</rule>
```

Please keep us posted, good luck and best regards,
Fernando Mendioroz

Comment: Hello,I have applied all the steps you specified, and the link between the gmlc and the STP server is up but now i get this error when i try to make a map ati request "15:27:06,574 ERROR [M3UAManagementImpl] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-4-thread-1) Tx : No AS found for routing message TransferMessage: {528=Protocol opc=89 dpc=42 si=3 ni=2 sls=3}
"

Comment: Hello again Fernando, after looking at the github repository of restcomm gmlc i found that the latest binary release i use is from 20th september 2016, and there is no newest one available, and the issue i'm facing where already raised in Restcomm Gmlc google group in 2016. There fore i suppose the issue has been handled since there. Can you please provide me the latest binary release?

Comment: Will i have to install it from the source code as specified in github?

Comment: Hi @NDZIEPatrickJoel,

You can always find latest releases here: https://github.com/RestComm/gmlc/releases You may do it both ways.

Anyway, this seems to be a configuration issue. Did you make the changes with the GMLC down, then restarted it? You need to stop the JBoss server, then do the modifications and after that start it again, so the new parameters are taken.

Comment: Hello @Fernando Mendioroz i have successfully set up the gmlc server and the link between, the STP and the GMLC is up, but when i try a map ati request (curl -X POST http://172.21.75.34:8080/restcomm/gmlc/rest?msisdn=237699947943
) I get this error  **The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request ()** But when i try the same request with the dummy msisdn **19395550113** i have a response. What does it means please?

Comment: This is what i get in the server log **2018-01-31 17:03:15,584 ERROR [org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.SignalingNetworkManagementHandler] (Thread-37) Rx : DUNA =DUNA Params(AffectedPointCode pointCode=[78] mask=[0], ) But AppServer Functionality is not As. Sending back ErrorCode.Unexpected_Message**

Comment: Hi @NDZIEPatrickJoel, glad you managed to get the links up. There's nothing wrong with the command, it should work. But for the server log you are providing, you are getting a DUNA (Destination UNAvailable). Something is wrong between the GMLC and the core network. Another problem you might get is that GMLC GT must be permitted in the HLR for performing ATI, otherwise you will get an ATI not allowed error. Do you have a pcap trace to look at?

Comment: Hello Fernando, here are some lines that i captured with wireshark.                0.498697613 192.168.212.185 -> 172.21.75.34 SCTP 70 HEARTBEAT 
0.498753415 172.21.75.34 -> 192.168.212.185 SCTP 70 HEARTBEAT_ACK 
1.115210818 192.168.212.185 -> 172.21.75.34 SCTP 70 HEARTBEAT 
1.117412789 172.21.75.34 -> 192.168.212.185 SCTP 70 HEARTBEAT_ACK 
1.735153820 192.168.212.185 -> 172.21.75.34 SCTP 70 HEARTBEAT 
1.735212449 172.21.75.34 -> 192.168.212.185 SCTP 70 HEARTBEAT_ACK (172.21.75.34 is the GMLC IP  and 192.168.212.185 is the STP IP)

Comment: Hello Fernando, Can you please provide me a working configuration for Restcomm GMLC and HLR? Maybe it will help me figure out what i am doing wrong. tshark trace only shows HEARTBEAT and  HEARTBEAT_ACK, but no message is initiated by the GMLC.

Comment: @NDZIEPatrickJoel I'm sorry but I cannot publicly give neither configuration nor traces of customer's GMLC live deployments, among many, for non-disclosure agreements between parties. I could give you a simple configuration case with scrambled numbers of SS7 credentials of a real life deployment, but anyway I'd need authorization from the executive team. Please, send an email to info@telestax.com or consider acquiring professional services and we'd gladly help you to sort this out. Or refer to our online documentation: https://www.restcomm.com/docs/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_managing