# undefined service for RestComm GMLC v1.0.66

Tags: restcomm

I have successfully set up Restcom GMLC after going through some issues ([Restcomm gmlc configuration issue no local SSN is present for primary Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799625/restcomm-gmlc-configuration-issue-no-local-ssn-is-present-for-primary-address/48195489#48195489)) Now the link beween the GMLC and the STP is up.
When i open the jss7-management console i have the error on the screen

[image]

When i try a map ati request (curl -X POST 172.21.75.34:8080/restcomm/gmlc/rest?msisdn=237699947943 ) I get this error The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request But when i try the same request with the dummy msisdn 19395550113 i have a response.

What i think i'm unable to perform a map ati request because of this error **undefined service for RestComm GMLC v1.0.66**, somehow a certain service is not started but i don't know which.